# AWS Cognito GetDetails() Method not calling

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito for my app Sign In and Sign up. In my app first the user register with email and phone number. After that, I'm redirecting to Verification Screen(Here OTP is sending by Cognito) After Verifying the OTP user will create some stores and then enter into the Dashboard. In this flow, I want to get the User details Attribute from Cognito in Verification code success. I've implemented the `getDetails()` method to get the `userAttributes` in Verification code success but it is not calling. I need the `userAttributes` when the time of store creation. Any help appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func submitButtonAction(_ sender: GradientButton) {


    let code = firstChar+secondChar+thirdChar+fourthChar+fifthChar+sixthChar
    guard code.count == 6 else{
        self.showAlert(message: ErrorMessages.kEnterValidOTP)
        return
    }

    let currentUser = self.userPool?.getUser("xxxx@gmail.com")
    currentUser?.confirmSignUp(code, forceAliasCreation: true).continueWith(block: { [weak self] (task) -> Any? in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                if let message = error.userInfo["message"] as? String{
                    self?.showAlert(message: message, onOkAction: {
                        strongSelf.clearTextFieldData()
                    })
                }else{
                    self?.showAlert(message: error.localizedDescription, onOkAction: {
                        strongSelf.clearTextFieldData()
                    })
                }
            }else{
                print(task.result)
                strongSelf.clearTextFieldData()
                print(AWSUserDetails.shared.userPool.currentUser()?.username)
                let user = AWSUserDetails.shared.userPool.currentUser()
                 //I've tried the above `user` and `currentUser`. But not working.
                user?.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (task) -> Any? in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if task.error == nil{
                            print(task.error)
                        }else{
                            print(task.result)
                        }
                    }
                })

           //     strongSelf.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifiers.createStoreSegue, sender: self)
            }
        }

        return nil
    })

}
```

Comment: Did you have any success with this?

Comment: Nope. But if the user is successfully registered then I'm getting the user details from the `GetDetails` method when the user is logged in. So, I've changed my app flow according to that.